# Boat; How to charge Leisure batteries the first time?

Tags: voltage, batteries, current

I will have 4 x 12V 100ah leisure batteries for my boat. They will be wired in parallel(using staggered wiring). My alternator is 12V 50amps. The batteries will be charged when the boat is moving. Therefore, best case scenario dictates it will take at least 8 hours for the bank to charge (400/50amps).

The problem is I will not have the luxury of leaving the motor on for 8 hours when the batteries first arrive. At best I will have about 3 hours a day. They will also be used during that time.

The question is will I be seriously affecting the lifetime of my batteries by not charging them fully the first time they are used? Do brand new Marine Leisure batteries ever arrive fully charged?

Comment: Just a suggestion; Install a Bank A/B switch, in the event some batteries have insufficient power to start the engine.
Remember when charging which bank (A) OR (B) OR (A+B) develop a system. Four 100ah batteries in parallel have plenty of power to burn up a boat. Fuse, or fusible link with a spare and tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lead-Acid batteries are normally delivered in a [fully charged state](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_charge_when_to_charge_table). They are freshly filled with full-strength acid.

If in doubt, charge it onshore using a charger designed for the purpose.